# active record validations - mutually exclusive attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to validate attributes in my model such that if one is present other should not be. Suppose there are 2 attributes -

```
if a present:
  b should be NULL
  c should be NULL
```

How can I use validates to do this?

`:validates a, b => NULL, c => NULL`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom validation:

```
validate :check_presence

def check_presence
  if !self.a.blank?
    if !self.b.blank? or !self.c.blank?
      errors[:base] << " b and c should be null."
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it quite readable to use `:absence` with `if:` like so :

```
validates :b, :absence, if: :a
validates :c, :absence, if: :a
```

Or if you also want complete mutual exclusiveness for `a`, `b` and `c`:

```
validates :a, :absence, if: ->(r) { r.b || r.c }
validates :b, :absence, if: ->(r) { r.a || r.c }
validates :c, :absence, if: ->(r) { r.a || r.b }
```

Or using a method:

```
validate :ensure_mutual_exclusion

def ensure_mutual_exclusion
  errors.add(:base, "...") if [a, b, c].count(&:present?) > 1
end
```